# Determine whether NSManagedObject attribute is optional

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am using Core Data and have a subclass of `NSManagedObject` called `Person` (which is an entity in Core Data). The Person object has several properties (e.g. `firstName`, `lastName`, etc.) and relationships (e.g. `friends`, `coWorkers`). Some of these attributes are optional, whereas others are mandatory.

Given a `Person` object how can I efficiently determine whether a particular property or relationship is optional or mandatory?

I want to try and avoid having to do some kind of inefficient loop through each attribute of the Person object, as I will need to call the code fairly often, so something similar to the pseudocode below would be perfect:

```
if ( [[aPerson getProperty:@"firstName"] isOptional] ) {

    // do stuff

}
```

...but I am not sure whether it could be done that simply. The above pseudocode would also only check properties, so I am guessing something else would need to be done in case the attribute being checked is a relationship.

I realize that it is probably more efficient to do a single loop and store the name of all the mandatory attributes in an array (then just check that array for the presence of the attribute name) and that's what I am doing at the moment, but unfortunately it doesn't really work with the structure of my code (thus the need for a more "on-demand" approach).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you are confusing entities with managed objects. "Optional" is an attribute only of entities. That is defined in the managed object model file and cannot change once a context has been assigned to it. If an entity has an optional relationship then all the managed objects initialized with that entity have that optional relationship and that will never change. You have no need to ever check a managed object for an optional relationship and you should know what the relationships are in the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function in your base subclass

```
NSDictionary *d = [[self entity] attributesByName];
NSAttributeDescription *attr = (NSAttributeDescription *)[d objectForKey:@"test"];
BOOL isopt = [attr isOptional];
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Elias! I made this a category on NSManagedObject and it works great :)

Comment: +1 This works but is pointless. (See my comment above.) You never have any need to check to the configuration of a particular managed object's relationships because all object initialized with the same entity have the exact same relationship configuration.